Bluetooth "setting "
After reboot and with Bluetooth device NOT powered up , the device
shows in Bluetooth->Settings as "disconnected".
That to me implicates  that OS (Ubuntu 22.04.4) is using some kind of database and does not actually scans for  the Blueto0th devices on boot.
Is there a configuration I am missing?

What do you expect from an unpowered device?  There's no database involved. Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b 0.

A device connected via bluetooth? Such devices are commonly paired with the computer, and this association exists even if the device is powered off. What are you trying to achieve?

please read the post,  I expect NON POWERED device NOT to be detected in any form  I used the term non powered to specify the device DOES NOT exist, hence it should not be  displayed on boot. OS is detecting the device from unknown source, not as a result of scanning for Bluetooth devices signals. PS "Bluetooth manager"  does not use term "paired" - it appears to have its own terminology. Therefore I cannot tell if the device was previously paired. I like  to explore this "previously paired " theory - hopefully it is in  specification.
